# socket.accept() is not working when running the script in cygwin

Tags: python, sockets, cygwin

I tried to run a basic python TCP server in cygwin. But somehow the socket.accept() method failed. The server seemed to be active because when typing the address 127.0.0.1:8080 in the browser the browser was loading...

After that I tried the script in the normal cmd.exe and it worked fine. Someone has an explanation for that?

Here my code:

```py
import socket

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# get local machine name
host = '127.0.0.1'

port = 9999

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)

while True:
    # establish a connection
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

    msg='Thank you for connecting'+ "\r\n"
    clientsocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Cygwin may have an old built in different version. Check versions from cygwin and cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolves after installing a cygwin1.dll from the April 4, 2018 snapshot,

> https://cygwin.com/snapshots/.

Thanks to Corinna Vinschen and Mark Geisert for the follow-up,

> https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-04/msg00019.html

I reproduced the issue by sending a TCP request,

```
$ { echo test; sleep 1; } | /cygdrive/c/util/nc/nc.exe -v -w 2 127.0.0.1 9999
HOSTNAME [127.0.0.1] 9999 (?) open
```

while letting your Python code listen,

```
$ python accept.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "accept.py", line 20, in <module>
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 206, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
socket.error: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

Not sure if this is related, but I came to your post after I observed an error in `startxwin` (when XWin receives a connection request from an X11 client such as xterm),

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXAccept: accept() failed
```

and in `sshd` (after sending a test request as above to port 22),

```
C:\cygwin64>c:\cygwin64\usr\sbin\sshd.exe -ddd
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 209
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/sshd_config len 209
debug3: /etc/sshd_config:54 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: /etc/sshd_config:126 setting Subsystem sftp     /usr/sbin/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:XXXXXXX
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:XXXXXXX
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXXXXXX
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:XXXXXXX
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 3 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
accept: Bad address
```

<s>Some observed similar errors [Cygwin Bad Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282032/cygwin-bad-address) but theirs was either resolved with a year 2014 Cygwin snapshot or with installing a 32-bit Cygwin.  I wonder if the latter relates to a WOW64 bug in Windows,</s>

http://zachsaw.blogspot.ca/2010/11/wow64-bug-getthreadcontext-may-return.html

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 XXXXXX 2.10.1(0.325/5/3)  x86_64 Cygwin
```