# "gethostname: bad address" from ssh-keygen

Tags: git-bash, ssh-keygen

While generating SSH key from git bash in windows I am getting the following error

```
gethostname: Bad address.
```

I am using the following command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "<your email address>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now
Need to use git-cmd

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when used [in parallel with Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23282032/6309)

If git-cmd works, you can use ssh-keygen directly, or type "bash", and use the same command from the bash session.

I prefer setting a custom path to make sure there is no interference between Git and any other program with, in a CMD:

```bash
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "GH=C:\Program Files\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

From there, a `bash` or a `ssh-keygen` would work in that same CMD.

Comment: what do you mean with 'if git-cmd works, you can use ssh-keygen directly'?

Comment: @SvenvanderBurg It means your `%PATH%` would already reference `C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin`, which includes `ssh-keygen.exe`. If not, the answer shows how to setup such a `%PATH%`.